# how to customize font size of button title of UIAlertController in IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

How to change font size of button title of UIAlertController with UIActionSheet Style in IOS 8.

i have tried following function but this is not working for IOS8.

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    for (UIView *_currentView in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:_currentView.frame];
            l.text = [(UILabel *)_currentView text];
            [l setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:20]];
            [actionSheet addSubview:l];
            _currentView.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is it? `UIActionSheet` (as shown in your code) or `UIAlertController` (as stated in your question)?

Comment: i used UiAlertController with UIActionSheetStyle...

Comment: `UIAlertController` doesn't use any of the `UIActionSheet` delegate methods so the code you posted will never be called.

Comment: yes you are right, but how can i solve this issue?

Comment: There is no API to customize `UIAlertController`. Use a 3rd party implementation (or write your own) that supports customization.

Comment: can i use UiActionSheet delegate methods in IOS8 or Not?

Comment: You can if you use `UIActionSheet`.